# Definite integral by substitution

Tags: definite-integrals

[image]

Why isn't the answer (d) but (b)? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Then could you tell me why it's not (d)?

Answer (score 2):

You get a factor of two from the square root upon subbing $x=(u-1)/2$, but also a factor of $1/2$ from $dx=du/2$.  These cancel each other out.  Also, the limits in $u$ are $2(-1/2)+1=0$ and $2(-1/4)+1=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $u=cosx$ then $1-u^2=1-cos^2x=sin^2x$

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the limits of the integration. Putting $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{1}{4}$ into $u=2x+1$ will give you the limits in (b).